# SPFx: Can we safely use eval or is it evil in SPFX?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I have used JavaScript since it was called LiveScript,
and know to value persons who say "*Eval is Evil*"
(Classic SharePoint uses `eval()` at least 5 times in its core code)

So when a new kid on the block gets (a bit) Evil,
starts telling you how to behave,
and restricts your capabilities,
 you counter it with Creativity:

```
  this.domElement.innerHTML = eval(
      `var s=document.createElement("SCRIPT");
       s.type="text/javascript";
       s.src="https://365csi.nl/hello_spfx.CSI.js";
       document.head.appendChild(s);');
```

#### Questions

- Can we safely use standard ECMAscript eval() in SPFX?
- There are ways of crippling `eval()`;
  as **Classic** SharePoint uses eval itself in its core code,
  will SPFx / New Experience **not** be more  Evil on us?
- Is eval used in new SharePoint code?
  Haven't had time yet to do a code analysis...
  Seems kinda pointless with an update every couple of weeks:
  [image]
  (*script:0 is my auto-check if UserCustomActions are enabled again*)

Comment: Clever title, but not sure what you're asking here...

Comment: Question: can I safely use standard eval() in SPFx?

Comment: Okay can you edit the question so the title is clear, and just one question that maybe someone working on SPFx can answer. Thanks.

Comment: This is probably gonna end up a Community question anyway, as there won't be a definite right/wrong answer, more likely just an overwhelming "No, don't do that. You can, but there's probably better way".

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you mean by "restrict your capabilities", (why you need a workaround)?

Comment: The joyful days of *just copy-paste some lines in a CEWP* for Generation J(Query) are gone with SPFx forcing the AMD pattern on you. It feels kinda like IKEA requiring you need a whole Snap-On toolset to put your next Billy together. SharePoint Fronteers (like you) have invested a lot in the past 10 years.. it takes some effort to massage legacy code into SPFx (too much IMHO) [PS. good to see you are back on SO] My Post partly was to poke and peek [sic] who responded with what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I.believe you can use it. As you mention its generally not a good practice, but you can use it. I don't believe we use it in any of our code.  Are you encountering any issue?

Comment: Honestly I don't like this answer. You can't make such a statement on the safety of eval without knowing the details of the implementation and the reasons behind it.